# What is the difference between these two instance methods?

Tags: c#, instance

What is the difference between these two instance methods?

```
public class Food
{
    public int apples;
    public int oranges;
    public int bananas;

    // Constructor #1
    public Food(int a, int o, int b) 
    { 
        apples = a;
        oranges = o;
        bananas = b;
    }

// Is this an instance

public Food myFood = new Food(5, 8, 1);

// Or this 

Food.myfood(5, 8, 1)
```

My more experienced friend said that the latter was the instance, not the first one.

Comment: I have a friend that's familiar with 5 languages and he said that the ladder is how you instance. I was just seeing whether I was right or him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like people aren't even reading the question.
ANSWER: The first one is creating a new instance of food (the former)

```
Food myFood = new Food(3,4,5);
```

The second one is incorrectly setting the value. After the f

```
Food myFood = new Food(3,4,5);
Console.WriteLine(myfood.Oranges) // prints 4;
myFood.Oranges = 3; // set the value of oranges for that object to 3
Console.WriteLine(myFood.Oranges); // prints 3;
```

Comment: Thankyou! Glad you actually answered the question :)

Comment: No problem sir. And don't worry about getting downvoted. Haters are gonna hate. They don't read/understand so they assume it's a problem with the question. It was a perfectly legitimate question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've forgotten to close your class.

```
public class Food
{
    public int apples;
    public int oranges;
    public int bananas;

    // Constructor #1
    public Food(int a, int o, int b) 
    { 
        apples = a;
        oranges = o;
        bananas = b;
    }

} // <----  you were missing this I assume

// If the following is in your main method, then myFood is an instance
// of the Food class. 
// you can do myFood.apples = 4; // very bad btw, having public variables.
public Food myFood = new Food(5, 8, 1);

// Not even sure what this is ... because you don't have a myFood on Food.
// If you would have a static property on your Food class (Yummy), then you
// could do something like Food.Yummy = what_ever_the_type_is ... 
Food.myfood(5, 8, 1)
```